# select element selected item is reset after it's bound

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a select element which is bound to a collection:

```
 <select data-bind="options: $data.monthlyBudgetRowTypes, optionsValue: 'key', optionsText: 'name', value: $data.selectedTypeId"></select>
```

*monthlyBudgetRowTypes* is an observableArray inside a Row class:

Inside that class there an observable called **selectedTypeId**.
It represents the selected option value.

I have a computed observable inside the Row class called **selectedTypeText** which represents the option text.
whenever the **selectedTypeId** changes, its text should change.

```
 function Row() {
      this.monthlyBudgetRowTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
      this.selectedTypeId = ko.observable();
      this.selectedTypeText = ko.computed(function (ev) {
        if (this.selectedTypeId()) {
            var itemType = this.monthlyBudgetRowTypes().filter(function (elem, i, temp) {
                return elem.key() == this.selectedTypeId();
            }.bind(self));
            if (itemType.length > 0) {
                return itemType[0].name();
            }
        }
    }, this);
}
```

I have a temp array which I add my rows to:

```
                row = new model.IncomeRow();
                row.monthlyBudgetRowTypes(incomeTypes);
                row.amount(item.IncomeAmount);
                row.date(item.IncomeDate);
                row.selectedTypeId(item.IncomeName);
                row.accountKey(item.MonthlyIncomeKey);
                row.datepickerID = 'inc_' + item.MonthlyIncomeKey;

                tempTableRows.push(row);
```

and after I finished adding all the rows, I add the temp array into the real rows array - observablearray.

```
incomeRows(tempTableRows);
```

The thing I don't understand is, the selected text item gets bound 2 times.
The first time with the correct value. But when I add all the items in the temp array into the observableArray, the select element gets bound and all the values gets the 1th item in the dropdown.

Here's my view:

```
  <div class="rows" data-bind="foreach:$component.incomeRows">
                <div class="t-tr" data-bind="css:$data.isNewRow()? 't-tr add':'t-tr', visible: $data.isVisible">
                    <div class="t-td td-1">
                        <select data-bind="options: $data.monthlyBudgetRowTypes, optionsValue: 'key', optionsText: 'name', value: $data.selectedTypeId"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-2">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput :$data.amount" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-3">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.description" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-4">
                        <input type="text" class="input-date" data-bind="value:$data.date, attr:{id: datepickerID}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-5">
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value:$data.origin" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-6">
                        <span data-bind="click: $component.loadIncomeToDesired, css:$data.isNewRow()? 'plus' : 'circle'"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-td td-7">
                        <span class="bin-icon" data-bind="click: $data.setDeletedRowState, css: $data.forDelete()? 'bin-icon selected' : 'bin-icon'">מחק</span>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- t-tr -->
            </div><!-- mo-table -->
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: How are you binding incomeRows observable array to the view? All rows at once? May be all selects have the same id? Can you add the view to the post? It happens after apply bindings right? Or just when building income rows?

Comment: @tede24 - yes all rows at once. I don't have any id set to the select elements. Yes, it happens after the binding is applied.

Comment: What is the `self` you are binding to in `}.bind(self))` ? Did you mean `}.bind(this))` ?

Comment: Check if key properties of $data.monthlyBudgetRowTypes has same type as $data.selectedTypeId and contains its value.

Comment: Second @NikolayErmakov. In essence, we need a repro, preferably a running one (e.g. with a Stack Snippet). (When you do so, it also wouldn't hurt to remove the bits that are *not* needed: several extra observables, loads of classes in markup, etc, etc.; the easier your question is to understand, the easier and more likely we'll be able to help.)

Comment: @NikolayErmakov - you are right, it should be bound to "this" but it still doesn't solve the issue.
 I checked the types. selectedTypeId  is a number like the key

Answer (score 0):

Your optionsValue binding is "key", but when you build the Row you are setting selectedTypeId with ItemName, used as optionsText not optionsValue.

Comment: You are right. It's not a bug but a bad design. This is how I'm getting the id of the rowType from an external web api.

Comment: ok, so maybe you can use just name as key and value as a regular select, and then convert name to id in backend.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's stupid but I found the problem. I have two tables and each row in each table has it's own types collection. Apparently I added the wrong types into the wrong collection.
Anyway, it's a pure coding bug on my side.